# How to put the following figure side by side in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, positioning

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}

%\textit{$U$}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.80,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=purple,
         thick,
         inner sep=1pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm
       }
     ] 


           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=below:1]{};
           \node (a2) at (0,2)[acteur,label=above:2]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (1.4,1) [acteur,label=below :3]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (3.4,1) [acteur,label=below:4]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (4.8,0) [acteur,label=below:5]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (4.8,2) [acteur,label=above:6]{};


           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a3); 
           \draw(a3) -- (a4);
           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a3);
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a5);
           \draw (a5) -- (a6);
          %\draw (-2.4, 3) node {$G$};


         \end{tikzpicture} 
%\hspace{2mm}
%\textit{$U^{+}$}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.80,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=blue,
         thick,
         inner sep=1pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm
       }
     ] 


           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=below:1]{};
           \node (a2) at (0,2)[acteur,label=above:2]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (1.4,1) [acteur,label=below :3]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (2.9,1) [acteur,label=below:4]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (2.9,2.2) [acteur,label=above:5]{};
           \node (a6) at (4.2,2.2) [acteur,label=above:6]{};
           \node (a7) at (4.2,1) [acteur,label=below:7]{}; 
           \node (a8) at (5.6,1) [acteur,label=below :8]{}; 



           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a3); 
           \draw(a3) -- (a4);
           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a3);
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a5);
           \draw (a5) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a6) -- (a7);
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a7);
           \draw  (a7) -- (a8);
           % \draw (-2.4, 3) node {$H$};


         \end{tikzpicture} 
         %\hspace{2mm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.10,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=violet,
         thick,
         inner sep=1pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm
       }
     ] 


           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=below:1]{};
           \node (a2) at (1.4,0)[acteur,label=below:2]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (2.8,0) [acteur,label=below :5]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (4.2,0) [acteur,label=below:6]{}; 
           \node (a9) at (5.6,0) [acteur,label=below:9]{};
           \node (a10) at (7,0) [acteur,label=below:10]{};
           \node (a7) at (4.2,1) [acteur,label=left:7]{}; 
           \node (a8) at (5.6,1) [acteur,label=right :8]{};
           \node (a4) at (2.1,1) [acteur,label=left :4]{};
           \node (a3) at (2.1,2) [acteur,label=left:3]{};



           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a5); 
           \draw (a5) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a6) -- (a9);
           \draw (a9) -- (a10);
           \draw [dashed](a8) -- (a9);
           \draw [dashed] (a6) -- (a7);
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a2);
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a5);
           \draw (a4) -- (a3);
           \draw (a7) -- (a8);
         %  \draw (-1.4, 2) node {$K$};


         \end{tikzpicture} 


\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to put the three figure in the same horizontal position, side by side. How to do this?

Comment: Don't leave any all-blank lines between the 2nd and 3rd pictures. (Remember: For TeX, all-blank lines are interpreted as a paragraph break.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To align figures built with TikZ, it is enough to build each of them in a `scope` environment and to `shift` the latter.
2. I factorized the options of each figure with `\tikzset`, which lightens the code:

   ```
   \tikzset{every path/.style=thick,
          acteur/.style={
            circle,
            fill=blue,
            thick,
            inner sep=1pt,
            minimum size=0.2cm
          }}
   ```
3. To write a text in the middle and below the three figures, it is enough to include them in a another `scope` environment. This environment itself defines a bounding box called `current bounding box`.
   Simply place this text to the `south` of this box and `anchor` it to the `north` so that the text does not overlap the 3 figures.

   ```
   \node[anchor=north] at (current bounding box.south){The solid edges are the matching edges};
   ```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{every path/.style=thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=blue,
         thick,
         inner sep=1pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm
       }}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
\begin{scope}
\begin{scope}
           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=below:1]{};
           \node (a2) at (0,2)[acteur,label=above:2]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (1.4,1) [acteur,label=below :3]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (3.4,1) [acteur,label=below:4]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (4.8,0) [acteur,label=below:5]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (4.8,2) [acteur,label=above:6]{};

           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a3); 
           \draw(a3) -- (a4);
           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a3);
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a5);
           \draw (a5) -- (a6);
          %\draw (-2.4, 3) node {$G$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=below:1]{};
           \node (a2) at (0,2)[acteur,label=above:2]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (1.4,1) [acteur,label=below :3]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (2.9,1) [acteur,label=below:4]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (2.9,2.2) [acteur,label=above:5]{};
           \node (a6) at (4.2,2.2) [acteur,label=above:6]{};
           \node (a7) at (4.2,1) [acteur,label=below:7]{}; 
           \node (a8) at (5.6,1) [acteur,label=below :8]{}; 



           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a3); 
           \draw(a3) -- (a4);
           \draw [dashed] (a1) -- (a3);
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a5);
           \draw (a5) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a6) -- (a7);
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a7);
           \draw  (a7) -- (a8);
           % \draw (-2.4, 3) node {$H$};
\end{scope} 

\begin{scope}[shift={(13,1)}] 
           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=below:1]{};
           \node (a2) at (1.4,0)[acteur,label=below:2]{}; 
           \node (a5) at (2.8,0) [acteur,label=below :5]{}; 
           \node (a6) at (4.2,0) [acteur,label=below:6]{}; 
           \node (a9) at (5.6,0) [acteur,label=below:9]{};
           \node (a10) at (7,0) [acteur,label=below:10]{};
           \node (a7) at (4.2,1) [acteur,label=left:7]{}; 
           \node (a8) at (5.6,1) [acteur,label=right :8]{};
           \node (a4) at (2.1,1) [acteur,label=left :4]{};
           \node (a3) at (2.1,2) [acteur,label=left:3]{};

           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw [dashed] (a2) -- (a5); 
           \draw (a5) -- (a6);
           \draw [dashed] (a6) -- (a9);
           \draw (a9) -- (a10);
           \draw [dashed](a8) -- (a9);
           \draw [dashed] (a6) -- (a7);
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a2);
           \draw [dashed] (a4) -- (a5);
           \draw (a4) -- (a3);
           \draw (a7) -- (a8);
         %  \draw (-1.4, 2) node {$K$};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\node[anchor=north] at (current bounding box.south){The solid edges are the matching edges};
         \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is good now

Comment: Is it possible to move the last graph a little above from its current position?

Comment: Yes, of course, just shift with `\begin{scope}[shift={(13,1)}]`. See my update.

Comment: very nice. I want to give a caption \caption{The solid edges are the matching edges} in the figure. How to do that?

Comment: Would you write that in the middle below the three figures?

Comment: yeah yeah.exactly

Comment: To write a text in the middle and below the three figures, simply include them in a new `scope` environment. Look at my update.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your answer